# Angular CLI deploy app to Heroku error in multi line css

Tags: angular, heroku, command-line-interface

I use primeng UI with angular cli 5, and I add css file path to angular-cli.json

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/Cupertino/theme.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
  ],
```

and deploy to Heroku and throw error

```
ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css ./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/Cupertino/theme.css ./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css
```

If I remove 3 lines of css path file, and heroku pass all and success deploy but the app not style.
Any one help me?

Comment: how are you building it?

Comment: sorry I don't understand?

Comment: How did you solve this error?